# how to insert two select in a select command of a sqldatasource

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have to insert two select in a select command of a sqldatasource that is linked to a dropdownlist but I don't know how to do it.

I tried it but it doesn't work:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConnection %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [RagioneSociale] FROM [Persona] 
WHERE Tipocliente = 2 AND SELECT [ID_Società] FROM [Persona] 
WHERE ID_Società IS NOT NULL"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

```
|ID    RagioneSociale    Piva              tipocliente  ID_Società|
|56    Amazon           33232432423         2           NULL      |
|80    plutooo           1231234            2            56       |
```

Comment: no, I put it by mistake now

Comment: You can't have two completely different sets of data (one with two columns, one with only one column) in one data source. When data has the same shape, you can use `UNION` / `UNION ALL` to combine queries. Or maybe you just want an extra condition in the `WHERE` (`AND / OR ID_Società IS NOT NULL`).

Comment: Why do you even need the extra select?

Comment: You can't just whack `AND` between two queries like that. That isn't valid SQL.

Comment: really? I'm asking on purpose

Comment: Can you give us a small example of what the 'persona' table looks like, and an example of what result you want the query to return?

Comment: there are also two different column-sets in selects

Comment: I have edited!!

Comment: @Elmachico could you put the expected output as well?

Comment: in the dropdownlist only the values that in id_Società are null appear to me

Comment: Tipocliente instead is linked in another table and the one already worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to do one `SELECT` statement but with two conditions. You can do it like this:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [RagioneSociale], [ID_Società] FROM [Persona] 
               WHERE Tipocliente = 2 AND ID_Società IS NOT NULL"
```

If you really want to do the two seperate queries then you'll have the `UNION` the table together or do two separate subqueries then `JOIN` them. However this will most likely result in a lot of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can make 2 select by using subquery, you can even put another where.

like :

```
SelectCommand=@"SELECT *, ID, (ANYTHING IN SUBQUERY)

               FROM ( 
                   SELECT [ID], [RagioneSociale] FROM [Persona] 
                   WHERE Tipocliente = 2 AND ID_Società IS NOT NULL 
                    )as SUBQUERY

               WHERE (STATEMENT)"
```